# Solving system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given these system of trigonometric equations below:

\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\beta) + 2 \tan(\gamma) &= 2 \\
\sin(\alpha) - 2 \cos(\beta) + \tan(\gamma) &= 3 \\
2 \sin(\alpha) - \cos(\beta) - 2 \tan(\gamma) &= 3
\end{align}

Should I transform those systems above into system of linear equation to solve them?

Note: constraints for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are $0 \le \alpha \le 2\pi$, $0 \le \beta \le 2\pi$, and $0 \le \gamma \le 2\pi$, respectively.

Comment: Why not? What happened when you tried?

Comment: Of course. Solve for $\sin\alpha$, $\cos\beta$ and $\tan\gamma$, then solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $$a=\sin(\alpha),b=\cos(\beta),c=\tan(\gamma)$$ we get the following System:
$$a+b+2c=2$$
$$a-2b+c=3$$
$$2a-b-2c=3$$
solving this System we get
$$a=\frac{5}{3},b=-\frac{7}{15},c=\frac{2}{5}$$
thus?
what tells you $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{5}{3}$$?

Comment: Solving for α, β, and γ

Comment: @BagasSanjaya I haven't checked the work, but taking it at face value, there is no real value of $\alpha$ that has a sine of $\frac 53$. Are you working in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Oh, I thought that my problem was from my math textbook and its writer didn't know that s/he might direct us to find imaginary solutions, while high school students only know real numbers....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By inspection, $(1+2)\sin\alpha=2+3$.

Then $(1-2)\sin\alpha+(1+2\cdot2)\cos\beta=2-2\cdot3.$

The rest is yours.